# VBA Word alignment syntax

Tags: vba, ms-word, alignment

**EDIT 1:**
I'm trying to format paragraph with a string (today's date) with right align in VBA, using Excel VBA test function as below. This line below I thought was acceptable syntax but I got something wrong here or somewhere else in the function, as date still displays left-aligned when I open the saved document:

```
wordLetter.Paragraphs(1).Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
```

This function creates new Word document with Normal template, adds the date, saves it relative to current Excel workbook location.

Otherwise, I understand `.Paragraphs(1)` exists already when a Word document is created with `.Add` or `.Open` method of `Documents` collection, I only just realised this.

```
Private Function Test()

    Dim objWord As Object: Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    objWord.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    objWord.Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wordLetter As Object: Set wordLetter = objWord.Documents.Add

    wordLetter.Range.Font.textColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)

    Dim strDate As String: strDate = Format(Now(), "dddd, mmm d, yyyy")

    wordLetter.Paragraphs(1).Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
    wordLetter.Paragraphs(1).Range.text = strDate

    objWord.Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    savePath = ThisWorkbook.path & "\testDoc.docx"

    With wordLetter
        .SaveAs2 Filename:=savePath, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Function
```

Many thanks any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

```
 WordLetter.Paragraphs(1).Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
```

Comment: Thanks kindly @Harassed , I see `paragraph.alignment` property in docs now. But this still makes date disappear, all the other text generated in this Word document shows fine. By kind chance, do you know if this means margin is doing something to make date disappear off right of document? Maybe I was just looking at old VBA code examples to begin on this route.. http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?29989-Solved-justify-paragraph-via-VBA

Comment: It aligns to the right hand margin of the paragraph - I'd check what that is set to in that paragraph using the ruler, it may be off the display area in the view you are using.